# How to not make a div get bigger when an item is added but also not change max-height

Tags: html, css

Sorry if its a dumb question but im making a ui thingy that I want to not get bigger when an item is added to it but also dont want change max-height

Comment: Welcome to SO, please share your attempts and codes to help you.

Comment: Give the div a `max-height` or `fixed height` and then apply an `overflow rule`. Then the div will stay at that set height and overflows according to your overflow rule without resizing the div.

Comment: Give an example of your div and adding element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click on the button, a new element will be added. This does not change the size *`("not make a div get bigger")`* of the div.

---

```
<div style="width:40px; max-height: 40px; overflow: auto; background: lightgreen">123 456 789 0 abc def xyz 123 456 789 0</div>
```

```js
function myfunc(){
   document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML += '<br>new_Item';
}
```

```css
#mydiv {
  width:100px; 
  max-height: 56px; 
  overflow: auto;    /* or: hidden */ 
  background: lightgreen
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">123 456 789 0 abc def xyz 123 456 789 0</div>
<button onclick="myfunc()">Add item to div</button>
```

Comment: @user14644277, clarify about your added items, please

Comment: @MaxiGui, looks like no explanations needed .. so contributor got what he wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use overflow on the div?

```css
div {
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of  `overflow-y:  scroll;` with some extra CSS to the child. It will add child items only horizontally instead of breaking into a new line.

```css
.container{
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: max-content;
}

.child{
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">I am first child</div>
  <div class="child">I am second</div>
  <div class="child">3rd</div>
  <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro itaque ad ipsum fugit assumenda sit sapiente soluta modi! Veniam, </div>
  <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod iste hic nam odit cupiditate similique quia facilis, corporis fugit sit, reiciendis, explicabo sapiente. Minima aliquam dolore velit, eius non beatae?</div>
  <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod iste hic nam odit cupiditate similique quia facilis, corporis fugit sit, reiciendis, explicabo sapiente. Minima aliquam dolore velit, eius non beatae?</div>
  <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod iste hic nam odit cupiditate similique quia facilis, corporis fugit sit, reiciendis, explicabo sapiente. Minima aliquam dolore velit, eius non beatae?</div>
  <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod iste hic nam odit cupiditate similique quia facilis, corporis fugit sit, reiciendis, explicabo sapiente. Minima aliquam dolore velit, eius non beatae?</div>
  <div class="child">I am not nth</div>
  <div class="child">nth+1</div>
</div>
```